# Error creating Grails project in NetBeans

Tags: grails, netbeans-8.2

The error I have is the following:

```
Warning |
Unrecognized flag: non-interactive.
Resolving dependencies..
Error |
Specify an application name or use --inplace to create an application in the current directory
```

I'm following the steps that come on the [NetBeans](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/web/grails-quickstart.html) page.

I have installed:

- Grails 3.3.8.
- Groovy 2.4.15.
- NetBeans 8.2.

From console create a project using `grails create-app hello world` and in this case it seems that there were no problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NetBeans doesn't currently support Grails 3.x as far as I know, however you might be able to import it as a Gradle project. I know that Netbeans is working on updating there Groovy support soon, maybe that will help...

The best IDE for Grails is Intellij Ultimate, which costs money, however you can use the community version, you just won't get GSP support.